# Access next array element value in PHP

Tags: php

I have this array

```
array:4 [
  0 => "B"
  1 => "C"
  2 => "D"
  3 => "A"
]
```

I want to traverse through this array

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
      {
        if($i==0)
        {   
          $sequence_arr[]=$array[$i].''.$array[$i+1];
        }
        else
        { 
          $sequence_arr[]=$array[$i].''.$array[$i+1];
        }
      }
```

when i'm trying to access element from `$array[$i+1]` i get message

> {message: "Undefined offset: 4", exception: "ErrorException

`$array[$i]` this is working but i want to access the next element of i.

Any Solution Thanks

Comment: Stop your loop one step earlier: `$i + 1 < count($array)`

Comment: *"but i want to access the next element of i"* - When your loop is on the last element of the array, what would the "next element" be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no next element for the *last* element in the array, you should never access `$array[$i+1]` when `$i == count($array) - 1`.

Presumably you want to collect all pairs, but realise that the number of pairs is one less than there are elements in the array. So make your loop iterate one time less:

```
for ($i = 0; $i + 1 < count($array); $i++)
```

NB: I don't see a difference in what is done for `$i == 0` and the other cases.